# How to remove (replace) punctuation with regular expression?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to convert certain punctuation to a semicolon when creating objects with my form.

**Requirements:**

I want to convert:

- Spaces (1 or more)
- Dots
- Commas
- Colons
- Semicolons
- Asteriks
- Slashes
- Underscores

to semicolons.

**What I got so far:**

`$plates = preg_replace('/\s+/[.,:;*/\_]/g', ';', $license_plates);`

When I try executing this with http://regexr.com/, I don't get any result.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Remove `g` at the end of the regex. The `/` after `\s+` is either redundant, or should be escaped. What are the actual  requirements?

Comment: I want spaces (1 or more), dots, commas, colons, semicolons, asteriks, slashes and underscores to be converted to semicolons.

Comment: So, try `$plates = preg_replace('~\s+|[.,:;*/_]~', ';', $license_plates);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 issues: `/` after `\s+` should be changed to `|` as you want to use an *alternation* here, and `/g` modifier is not used with PHP regexes. Also, you do not need to escape `_` symbol.

Use

```
$plates = preg_replace('~\s+|[.,:;*/_]~', ';', $license_plates);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0xqtCX/1)

**Details**:

- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `[.,:;*/_]` - a single character in the set: `.`, `,`, `:`, `;`, `*`, `/`, or `_`. Note the use of a tilde as a [regex delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) allows using an unescaped `/` inside the regex pattern.

Comment: Where is the tilde used for?

Comment: It is a [regex delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), so as not to have to escape the forward slash in the regex pattern.